# Android Calculator keypad button OnClickListener not working?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

Hi i am implementing a Calculator type Keypad to my app where user click on the keypad it wants to display in Edittext but i am not getting any Error and also no result Here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
GridView mKeypadGrid;
KeypadAdapter mKeypadAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Get reference to the keypad button GridView
    mKeypadGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grdButtons);

    // Create Keypad Adapter
    mKeypadAdapter = new KeypadAdapter(this);

    // Set adapter of the keypad grid
    mKeypadGrid.setAdapter(mKeypadAdapter);

    // Set button click listener of the keypad adapter
    mKeypadAdapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button btn = (Button) v;
            // Get the KeypadButton value which is used to identify the
            // keypad button from the Button's tag
            KeypadButton keypadButton = (KeypadButton) btn.getTag();

            // Process keypad button
            ProcessKeypadInput(keypadButton);
        }
    });

    mKeypadGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });

}

protected void ProcessKeypadInput(KeypadButton keypadButton) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(
            MainActivity.this,
            keypadButton.getText().toString() + " "
                    + keypadButton.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
      }
```

Here is my KeypadAdapter.java

```
    public class KeypadAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public KeypadAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mButtons.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mButtons[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ButtonView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button btn;
    if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        btn = new Button(mContext);
        KeypadButton keypadButton = mButtons[position];

        // Set CalculatorButton enumeration as tag of the button so that we
        // will use this information from our main view to identify what to do
        btn.setTag(keypadButton);
    } 
    else {
        btn = (Button) convertView;
    }

    btn.setText(mButtons[position].getText());
    return btn;
}

// Create and populate keypad buttons array with CalculatorButton values
private KeypadButton[] mButtons = {KeypadButton.SEVEN,KeypadButton.EIGHT, KeypadButton.NINE, 
        KeypadButton.FOUR, KeypadButton.FIVE,KeypadButton.SIX, 
        KeypadButton.ONE, KeypadButton.TWO, KeypadButton.THREE,
        KeypadButton.ZERO,KeypadButton.DOT,KeypadButton.BACKSPACE };

public void setOnButtonClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public enum KeypadButton {
    BACKSPACE("Clear",KeypadButtonCategory.CLEAR)
    , ZERO("0",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , ONE("1",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , TWO("2",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , THREE("3",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , FOUR("4",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , FIVE("5",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , SIX("6",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , SEVEN("7",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , EIGHT("8",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , NINE("9",KeypadButtonCategory.NUMBER)
    , DOT(".",KeypadButtonCategory.OTHER);

    CharSequence mText; // Display Text
    KeypadButtonCategory mCategory;

    KeypadButton(CharSequence text,KeypadButtonCategory category) {
        mText = text;
        mCategory = category;
    }

    public CharSequence getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
public enum KeypadButtonCategory {
    MEMORYBUFFER
    , NUMBER
    , OPERATOR
    , DUMMY
    , CLEAR
    , RESULT
    , OTHER
  }
  }
```

so please help me to solve this Issue..........

Answer (score 0):

From what I know to make an item inside a gridView clickable you need to fully implement an onItemClickListener and using onClickListener the way you are is actually assigning that listener to the grid view and not each individual button in the grid view. I think if you take the code you have in your onClickListener and put it into your onItemClickListener then it should work.

```
mKeypadAdapter.setOnButtonClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //This won't work 
    //because keypadAdaptor.setOnButtonClickAdaptor(.....); is empty
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        Button btn = (Button) v; 
        KeypadButton keypadButton = (KeypadButton) btn.getTag();
        ProcessKeypadInput(keypadButton); 
    } 
});

mKeypadGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
    //This needs to be filled in with your button processing code
    } 
});
```

Also calling `keypadAdaptor.setOnButtonClickListener(onClickListener.....);`isn't going to do anything since your method definition for it in your keypadAdator is empty.

Comment: If you take The code from your OnClickListener and put it inside your OnItemClickListener then it should work you can remove the mKeyAdapter.setOnButtonClickAdapter since it isn't used.